# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Nested form and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have working on Nested form and Rails 4,

my code is,

```
<%= f.fields_for :event_timings do |builder| %>
                    <%= render :partial => 'events/event_timing', 
                               :locals => { :f => builder } %>
                <% end %>

                <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :event_timings %></p>
```

i am getting error as,
[image]

```
Missing partial events/event_timing_fields, application/event_timing_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/hhh/Documents/oise/oise/app/views"
  * "/home/hhh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bundler/gems/devise-40068c4cba07/app/views"
```

And for your information i have deleted the lines from layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And i have included application_jquery.js ref: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: is there any 'app/events/_event_timing.html' file ?

Comment: Yes, it's there!!! 'app/views/events/_event_timing.html.erb' file

Comment: Yes got the solution renamed _event_timing file as "_event_timing_fields".